# extreme ES6 Array extension weirdness. it reverts to regular Array with webpack only

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, ecmascript-6, webpack

[I'm rewriting question after simplifying and finding an answer of sorts. Bergi's helpful comments below refer to the older version.]

Webpack seems to mess up objects of classes that extend Array. This should work, I believe, and it does work in node and in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sigfried/n2pab49q/2/

```
  "use strict";
  class ThingArray extends Array {
      constructor(data, parentThing) {
          super(data);
          console.log(`sending a [${this.constructor.toString().replace(/.\n[\w\W]*$/,'')}] to thing.method`);
          debugger; // in browser console, type this.constructor, it shows
                    // ThingArray, but the console.log above shows Array
          test(this);
      }
  }

  function test(ta) {
        console.log(`I'm expecting a ThingArray, and what I'm getting is a [${ta.constructor.toString().replace(/.\n[\w\W]*$/,'')}]`);
        console.log(`Is it a ThingArray? The answer is ${!!(ta instanceof ThingArray)}`);
  }

  let twothings = new ThingArray(['baz',42]);
  console.log(twothings);

  if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      var div = document.getElementById('example');
      div.innerHTML = twothings;
  }
```

The code and my understanding of the problem were much more complex earlier.
I couldn't figure out what I was doing wrong. Bergi encouraged me to simplify and it looks like a webpack bug, as per the answer I've added below. But just in case I'm using webpack wrong, I'll include my webpack.conf.js and package.json

```
  var webpack = require('webpack');

  module.exports = {
    entry: [
      './index.js',
    ],
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
      loaders: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          loader: 'babel',
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          query: {
            presets: ['es2015']
          }
        },
      ]
    },
  };

  {
    "name": "array-extend-bug",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "description": "problem with webpack handling array extensions",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
      "build": "webpack-dev-server"
    },
    "repository": {
      "type": "git",
      "url": "git@gist.github.com:5c96b880d7986776e541.git"
    },
    "keywords": [
      "webpack",
      "es6",
      "bug"
    ],
    "author": "Sigfried Gold",
    "license": "MIT",
    "dependencies": {},
    "devDependencies": {
      "babel": "^6.3.26",
      "babel-core": "^6.0.12",
      "babel-loader": "^6.0.1",
      "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.0.12",
      "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.3.13",
      "webpack": "^1.12.10",
      "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Sorry, but if you cannot give us a code that reproduces this, we hardly can help you about it.

Comment: Well, there is code in the debugger images. I don't think you want a thousand lines of code, which is why I tried to replicate the problem in a short example. If I knew which part of the thousand lines to include, I would. If anyone can suggest how it's even possible for what I show in the two debugger images to happen, that would probably help me find the problem.

Comment: Try breaking it down by repeatedly scrapping half of the code as long as the problem persists.

Comment: Right. I sometimes do that. I'll try. Another hint, probably not much help: the library where my code occurs also works fine in my node.js test suite, but when I call it from a react component is when it's breaking. So I'll start trying to follow your suggestion with the react code.

Answer (score 3):

The ability to extend native types like `Array` is a brand new feature of ES6 and is only available using true ES6 class syntax. Since it is only available using true ES6 classes, it is also untranspilable.

It's working in Node because your V8 version supports native classes, and it doesn't work in Webpack because there does not exist a spec-compliant way to make it work in ES5.

If you really want to try to hack it in, you can use something like [`transform-builtin-extend`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-builtin-extend) but really I wouldn't recommend it since you'll be asking for trouble. If you need your code to work consistently on old and new environments, it is better not to subclass builtin constructors at all.

Comment: So that means I shouldn't be trying to extend Array for browser-friendly code at all?

Answer (score 1):

loganfsmyth is right, and I guess he's welcome to warn me away from https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-builtin-extend since he wrote it. On the Babel slack channel he helped me figure out how to get it working and it totally solved the problem. Here is my new webpack.conf.js. Besides babel-plugin-transform-builtin-extend, I also had to add babel-polyfill.

```
  var webpack = require('webpack');

  module.exports = {
    entry: [
      'babel-polyfill',
      './index.js',
    ],
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
      loaders: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          loader: 'babel',
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          query: {
            presets: ['es2015'],
            plugins: [
              ["babel-plugin-transform-builtin-extend", {
                globals: ["Array"],
              }]
            ]
          }
        },
      ]
    },
  }
```

This gist runs the example code from the question through webpack: https://gist.github.com/Sigfried/5c96b880d7986776e541. Take out the polyfill and the transform-builtin-extend and it will start failing again in the browser, but not in node.